# How to combine code for 2 responsive menus

Tags: jquery

I would like to put 2 responsive menus in one page, both exactly the same, one at the top and one at the bottom,
The HTML is as follows:-

```
 <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
```

and the jquery is:-

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        var pull        = $('#pull');
            menu        = $('nav ul');
            menuHeight  = menu.height();

        $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.slideToggle();
        });

        $(window).resize(function(){
            var w = $(window).width();
            if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                menu.removeAttr('style');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

If I create 2 class's id pull for the top with #pull in the jquery script as above

and id bottompull for the bottom with #bottompull in another jquery script

a) will this cause conflicts?

b) Is there a way of combining the scripts?

I've tried to add another variable for #bottompull here,

```
     <http://jsfiddle.net/rz85X/9/>
```

but this doesn't work

Can somebody please point me in the right direction please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code redefines the `pull` variable the second time you set it in your fiddle. What you need to do is have the code run for each instance of the menu, rather than both menus at once. I've updated your fiddle to use $.each to run for both menus separately: http://jsfiddle.net/jakelauer/rz85X/13/

Here's the code:

```
$(function() {
    var pull = $('#pull, #bottompull');

    pull.each(function(){
        $(this).on('click', function(e) {
            menu        = $(this).closest('nav').find('ul');
            menuHeight  = menu.height();
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.slideToggle();
        });
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(window).width();
        $('nav ul').each(function(){
            if(w > 320 && $(this).is(':hidden')) {
                $(this).removeAttr('style');
            }
        });

    });
});
```

EDIT: Updated to remove a couple errors

Comment: Ah, now it does! Thank you